# Returning x pages from a Word document and creating a new document with them

Tags: wpf, office-interop

Here is the plan - it's a good plan, but there is the proverbial brick wall. I have Word documents stored as Byte() on a database - I need to pull selected ones and save to a temp directory as word document. That is done and working. Next, I need to create a new document based on the first x pages of the original, save that to the temp directory - email the new file and delete the contents of the temp directory.

The only part I am stuck on is splitting the file by page number. This, as an example, returns the number of pages...

```
Public Function ReturnWordPages(FileName As String) As Integer
Try
    Dim WordApp As ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()
    Dim vFilename As Object = FileName
    Dim [readonly] As Object = False
    Dim isVisible As Object = True
    Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim wDoc As Document = WordApp.Documents.Open(vFilename, oMissing, [readonly], oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, isVisible)
    Dim vStat As WdStatistic = WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages
    Dim vNum As Integer = wDoc.ComputeStatistics(vStat, oMissing)
    Return vNum

Catch ex As Exception
    EmailError(ex)
    Return 0
End Try
End Function
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

======== UPDATE ===============

I have got a little further - able to copy the selected number of pages and save the new file, but in the process Word throws a popup - originalFile.docx is locked for editing by localComputerName - Do you want to open a read only copy, create as local copy....

How do I manage to get the entire process to run without prompts and opening and closing of the file? Also, it's not copying over page numbers (footers).

I have tried setting visible to false - that has no effect

```
 Public Function ReturnSplitDocument(FileName As String, vPages As Integer, outputPath As String) As Boolean
 Try
     Dim WordApp As ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()
     Dim BaseDoc As Document
     Dim DestDoc As Document
     Dim vWhat As Object = WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage
     Dim vWhich As Object = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst
     Dim vCount As Object = 1
     Dim vFilename As Object = FileName
     Dim [readonly] As Object = False
     Dim isVisible As Object = True
     Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
     BaseDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName)
     WordApp.Documents.Open(vFilename, oMissing, [readonly], oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, isVisible)


     Dim vStartRange As Range = WordApp.Selection.GoTo(vWhat, vWhich, vCount, oMissing)
     Dim vCount2 As Object = CInt(vCount) + vPages
     Dim vEndRange As Range = WordApp.Selection.GoTo(vWhat, vWhich, vCount2, oMissing)
     vEndRange.SetRange(vStartRange.Start, vEndRange.End - 1)
     vEndRange.Select()
     WordApp.Selection.Copy()
     DestDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
     DestDoc.Activate()
     WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
     DestDoc.SaveAs2(outputPath)
     DestDoc.Close()
     DestDoc = Nothing

     WordApp.Quit()
     WordApp = Nothing

     Return True

 Catch ex As Exception
     EmailError(ex)
     Return False
 End Try
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add another .visible = false whilst the application has the destination file open and before .activate.

```
Public Function ReturnSplitDocument(FileName As String, vPages As Integer, outputPath As String) As Boolean
Try
    Dim WordApp As ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()
    WordApp.Visible = False
    Dim BaseDoc As Document
    Dim DestDoc As Document
    Dim vWhat As Object = WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage
    Dim vWhich As Object = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst
    Dim vCount As Object = 1
    Dim vFilename As Object = FileName
    Dim [readonly] As Object = True
    Dim isVisible As Object = False
    Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    BaseDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(vFilename)
    WordApp.Documents.Open(vFilename, oMissing, [readonly], oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, isVisible, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing)


    Dim vStartRange As Range = WordApp.Selection.GoTo(vWhat, vWhich, vCount, oMissing)
    Dim vCount2 As Object = CInt(vCount) + vPages
    Dim vEndRange As Range = WordApp.Selection.GoTo(vWhat, vWhich, vCount2, oMissing)
    vEndRange.SetRange(vStartRange.Start, vEndRange.End - 1)
    vEndRange.Select()
    WordApp.Selection.Copy()
    DestDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
    WordApp.Visible = False  '<------------- Solution
    DestDoc.Activate()
    WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    DestDoc.SaveAs2(outputPath)
    DestDoc.Close()
    DestDoc = Nothing
    BaseDoc.Close()
    BaseDoc = Nothing

    WordApp.Quit()
    WordApp = Nothing

    Return True

Catch ex As Exception
    EmailError(ex)
    Return False
End Try
End Function
```